# Crack a user password

Tags: password, shadow

I need to crack a user password at /etc/shadow which is hashed in sha512 with specific known salt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the challenge is known to be intractable - the security mechanism is designed to make the requested operation impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not "crack" such password as by definition the hashing is not reversible.

If you have a list of possible candidates you can try to see if they match, after redoing the hashing with the appropriate salt.

If you do not have any starting list you are left with a brute force approach, trying all combinations until you hit the good one. Note that if the password is good enough security wise you will never find it by brute force.

John the Ripper (http://www.openwall.com/john/) is a well known software for brute force cracking.

Comment: The word "crack" is *exactly* what password-cracking enthusiasts/experts call the process of trying candidate passwords until you get the expected hash - and is exactly what the question is asking about. The words that we *don't* like are "decrypt" or "dehash", for the reason that you describe (it's not reversible, so no one is "de-"-ing anything).